# JQuery - Label .text() not correct

Tags: jquery

I am having an issue that I just can't figure out!

I am trying to identify a block on a page by if it contains a label with a certain value!

So I am looking for this label like this:

```
if ($('label[value|="<em>*</em>Choose your Design"]').length) {
  $(this).parent().parent().css("cssText", "width:22.5% !important; margin-right:1% !important;");
}
```

The problem is that the statement is true but I think it is only finding the * and not the Choose Your Design and so its not working as I want.

If I run inside the statement:

```
var tester = $(this).html();
alert(tester);
```

I simply get a * and nothing else.

Can anyone shed some light on how I can change my code so I can find this label, then identify its parent and add the class as this is my goal!

Thanks! :)

EDIT: Thanks for the suggestions contains works I think but my code still doesn't seem to work... Updated fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/mr5n9u2w/3](http://jsfiddle.net/mr5n9u2w/3)

Comment: `<label>` with an attribute `value`?

Comment: can you share the html sample

Comment: you might be looking for `:contains()`

Comment: I think the `value` part of your selector doesn't mean what you think it means.

Comment: see https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mr5n9u2w/1/

Comment: I Think contains is working but my code still doesn't seem to wrok updated Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mr5n9u2w/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help I needed the "contains" insteadl of "value"

if ($('label:contains("*Choose your Design")').length) {
}